# TS Error Type 'false' has no call signatures TS (2349)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I am getting a TS error on the SetIsActive and the error is 'This expression is not callable.
Not all constituents of type 'boolean | Dispatch<SetStateAction>' are callable.
Type 'false' has no call signatures.TS(2349)' Not really sure how to fix the error, Thanks in advance

the DetectOutsideClick Component has an error on 'e'  and 'contains' with the error "Property 'contains' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)"

```
import ArrowDown from '../../../assets/images/event-landing-pre-event/triangle-down.svg';
import { DetectOutsideClick } from './detect-outside-click';

export const DropDownButton = () => {
  const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = DetectOutsideClick(dropdownRef, false);
  const handleClick = () => setIsActive(!isActive);

  return (
    <div className="">
      <div className="">
        <button onClick={handleClick} className="flex items">
          <span className="text-blue-800 font-semibold mx-3">My registration</span>
          <img className="mr-1" src={ArrowDown} alt="User avatar" />
        </button>
        <nav
          ref={dropdownRef}
          className={`absolute top-8  w-80 opacity-0
          ${isActive ? 'opacity-100 visible' : ''}`}
        >
          <ul className="">
            <li className="block">
              <a href="#">Order Confirmation</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropDownButton;





import { useState, useEffect, MutableRefObject } from 'react';

export const DetectOutsideClick = (el: MutableRefObject<null>, initialState: boolean) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    const onClick = (e) => {
      if (el.current !== null && !el.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setIsActive(!isActive);
      }
    };

    if (isActive) {
      window.addEventListener('click', onClick);
    }

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', onClick);
    };
  }, [isActive, el]);

  return [isActive, setIsActive];
};
```

Comment: What is `DetectOutsideClick`?

Comment: a custom component that closes the dropdown menu if clicked outside the dropdown  menu

Comment: That's the part that looks to have the bug - you'll have to include it in your question for others to be able to figure out what's going wrong

Comment: ok thanks. will do

Comment: If you want to use TypeScript, you shouldn't use `any`, that defeats the whole purpose of TS

Comment: any has been removed

Answer (score 0):

Just use `return [isActive, setIsActive] as const;` and you'll be good to go.

Like our buddy @tokland told on his answer, TS has no way to tell a tuple from an array and resuming it, `as const` does that for you.

You can read more and learn with other examples on the oficial TS documentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions)